# How to use keras vis (gradcam, saliency map) on google colab?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, attribution

I would like to use keras vis library in google colab to display saliency maps and grad cams of my keras model.

Keras vis is old and unmaintained and uses a deprecated function from scipy 1.1.0. Google colab has scipy on version 1.7.3.

```
from vis.visualization import visualize_cam
```

The above line gives me the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'imresize' from 'scipy.misc' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py)
```

I tried to uninstall scipy and install the version 1.1.0, but building the wheel takes forever / I cancelled it after trying for 2h...

Is there any other way how to use those functions from keras vis? Is there a better libary to display pixel attribution from keras models?

Comment: I found tf explain https://tf-explain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ that has a really nice API if someone is looking for something newer than keras vis